# Moving the navigation buttons to the left and the logo to the right

Tags: html, css

I would like to move the navigation buttons a little bit to the left and separate it from the last button which's **Sign Up**, at the same time, I need to move the logo a little bit to the right.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(212, 209, 209);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* so navbar will go under logo on small smartphones */
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.link {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

.link:hover {
  color: black;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
}

#signup {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="images/new logo.png" alt="logo">
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="link">Information</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Content</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="link">Pricing</a>
    <button class="link">Login</button>
    <button class="link" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Add a rough figure as to how you want the styling to be. Also, show what you have tried.

Comment: have you tried margins yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to move the logo to the right and signup to the left seperated from other navigation buttons then since its the first and last child, just use:

```
header:first-child{
   float: right;
}
header:last-child{
   float: left;
}
```

To adjust the middle buttons, just give a little bit of margin to position it correctly

Comment: poor solution and `mis-using` float as a hack. Espacially if the Op already uses Flexbox you could use the `order`-property. However, that is not what the OP asked for at all.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain my question in the correct way. I meant the logo looks to much on the left side and I would like to move it just a little bit to the right so it looks applicable. Regarding the navigation buttons, I want them to be little bit on the left, so that they are not so close to the last Sign Up button.

Comment: then why checked it as an answer when this does not do what you want?

Comment: @Mr.Faraj so is the problem solved or you still need a solution? Also why is using `top` and `left` not enough to shift things by a few pixels? eg: `left: -5px`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `margin-left` to your logo to move it more to the right. If you want more space between the last button and the rest of the content you can also add a `margin-left` to the `.link:last-child` If you want elements to space apart then use `margin`. `margin: auto` will distribute all remaining space within flexbox and css-grid (just as a side note for the future):

```css
.logo {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.link:last-child {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

/* original CSS */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(212, 209, 209);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* so navbar will go under logo on small smartphones */
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.link {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

.link:hover {
  color: black;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
}

#signup {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="images/new logo.png" alt="logo">
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="link">Information</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Content</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="link">Pricing</a>
    <button class="link">Login</button>
    <button class="link" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Ok! Great. I tried the elements and it worked great. Now I'm stuck with another issue, the navigation items like the information button and the pricing link are still at the top and not at the same level as the other elements and I tried to search on google but couldn’t find a way to accomplish this step.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: rgb(212, 209, 209);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* so navbar will go under logo on small smartphones */
  align-items: inherit;
  padding: 15px 4%;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.logo {
    
    margin-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
      
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 0;
}

.link {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.link:hover {
    color: black;
}

.link:last-child {
    margin: auto;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
}

#signup {
    
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0,136,169,1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

give them all a little bit of margin in your css file. That's all I can tell you without seeing your CSS file

Comment: to broad. Please add more clarity with a definite and specific solution. preferably add a [repro] to provide additionald etails and validate your answer.

Comment: Couldn't really do that without his CSS file.

Comment: Then ask for more clarity as a comment, flag the answer and wait for a response.

Comment: Ok so if you add margin-left: 20px; (or whatever distance you want) to you link class in your css it should move them away from eachother. Then add margin-left: '10px' or so to your logo class, that should do what your asking

Comment: @tacoshy I believe that's what I was doing. If that wasn't clear I apologize. Clearly the OP got what I was asking for though, as he uploaded his CSS file...